MAC address gets disabled for wireless adapter (TP-linl TL-WN722N) on switching to monitor mode
When I type the command ifconfig on starting kali linux in virtual box I am not assigned a MAC address. See the terminal trace below.
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fd00::7648:cc8d:8ce9:810c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e9e0:a628:3268:d555  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:ad:25:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5  bytes 2724 (2.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25  bytes 3961 (3.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 06-F1-8D-DE-BA-70-00-94-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Then I reboot Kali linux by typing the command reboot. And a MAC address is assigned as shown in the terminal trace below.

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::e9e0:a628:3268:d555  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::7648:cc8d:8ce9:810c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 08:00:27:ad:25:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 3314 (3.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 4610 (4.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f2:d4:bd:ed:67:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Now I switch on the Monitor mode on the wireless adapter by typing the following commands.

> ifconfig wlan0 down
> iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
> ifconfig wlan0 up

Wireless adapter switches to monitor mode as shown below.

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifconfig wlan0 down
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifconfig wlan0 up          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# iwconfig                   
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Now if I type the command ifconfig, the MAC address disappear. See trace below.
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifconfig         
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::e9e0:a628:3268:d555  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::7648:cc8d:8ce9:810c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 08:00:27:ad:25:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6  bytes 3314 (3.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 4830 (4.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 480 (480.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec F2-D4-BD-ED-67-F3-00-9F-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Please help me out. This problem is inhibiting my cybersecurity studies.

The MAC address line is still there in your output:
unspec F2-D4-BD-ED-67-F3-00-9F-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Monitor mode literally means that the interface no longer uses emulated Ethernet (802.3) frames – it now sends/receives raw 802.11 frames (plus additional 'radiotap' metadata) – so accordingly it is no longer ether link type but instead becomes an ieee802.11/radiotap link; a type which ifconfig does not recognize.
Different link types may have different-size MAC addresses (e.g. FireWire uses 64/128-bit), so tools like ifconfig need to specifically know about each link type: how long its MAC address should be, whether it should be formatted in hex or ASCII or octal, etc. In this case ifconfig doesn't know the correct name and doesn't know how to format the address, so it gives you unspec and a "best effort" display of the full 16-byte buffer it receives from the OS.
(Adding to the problem, ifconfig uses an outdated SIOCGIFHWADDR interface which takes a fixed-size buffer and provides only the link type but not address size, therefore all 16 bytes have to be shown for unknown link types. The newer "netlink" interface would at least tell the program how long the IFLA_ADDRESS field actually is.)
More modern tools, such as ip link (from iproute2), know how to display 802.11 addresses:
$ ip link
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state ...
    link/ether 28:df:eb:13:2a:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ sudo iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
$ ip link
15: mon0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT ...
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 28:df:eb:13:2a:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ sudo iw mon0 del

Recognizing which tools are obsolete and what makes them obsolete should be an important part of cybersecurity studies.

Thanks @grawity :)

Entering monitor mode doesn't actually change the frame format the NIC uses when sending or receiving (obviously), but the frame format it exposes to the rest of the system.

Sure, but I wasn't talking about the NIC, but about the interface shown in ifconfig, which already is what the NIC('s driver) exposes to the rest of the system.
